# Does "exploit" (verb) inherently carry a negative connotation?

Tags: connotations

I want to use it to mean "thoroughly make use of ... without pushing it/them over its/their limit" but I am worried it does not mean that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exploit can carry a negative connotation of using someone else for your advantage and even being horrible to them.

Instead of exploit, I would say:

> **I benefited from *x*'s help**

This sounds much nicer than *I exploited x* and now does not carry a negative connotation but instead, it shows you made use of their help.

If you want to emphasise how much help they have you, you could say:

> I **thoroughly benefited** from *x's* help

This implies they benefited and helped you a lot, and you did not push them over their limit.

Comment: I would add emphasis to Daniil's first (relatively gentle) observation: In my experience *exploit* is universally, or very close to universally, negative, for things, for people, and for situations.